# Ошибка: не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Tags: node.js, npm

[image: скрин cmd]

Возникли проблемы при работе с nodejs

Например, когда вызываешь `npm --v` получается  вот это (см.ниже)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm --v
"CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
2.14.4
```

Вроде выводит версию, но перед этим выводит, как вы видите, какую-то ошибку что ли...

В чем проблема? Я не могу понять почему выводит какой-то `CALL`?

**Обновление**

```
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.

ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL

SET "NODE_EXE=%~dp0\node.exe"
IF NOT EXIST "%NODE_EXE%" (
  SET "NODE_EXE=node"
)

SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%~dp0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('CALL "%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" prefix -g') DO (
  SET "NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS=%%F\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
)
IF EXIST "%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%" (
  SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%"
)

"%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" %*
```

Извиняюсь за оформление. Это было содержимое `npm.cmd`.

Comment: пожалуйста, приводите текст в виде текста, а не в виде картинки.

Comment: @alexander barakin  а так понятно в чем проблема ?

Comment: @Aleksey посмотрите что вам выдает `where npm`. скорее всего это cmd-файл, и в нем то этот кривой `callё и написан.

Comment: @Aleksey ну вот этот CALL и падает - где-то что-то из переменных окружения криво прописано. проверяете его по шагам

Comment: Белым по чёрному написано же что "call ... " не является ни командой командного процессора cmd, ни программой. Очевидно 'CALL "%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" prefix -g' понимается как запуск команды/программы с таким вот экзотическим названием (не только лишь кал, но и всё между одиночных кавычек. просто call - есть такая команда). А в самом конце запускается ваш node нормальным, а может и нет образом. Может и нет - потому что не понятно что хотели сделать этим калом, от которого только ... ошибки. Можете игнорировать это, а может надо написать гневное письмо разработчику node.

Answer (score 1):

Запрашивать версию надо одним из следующих способов:

```
-v
--version
```

Насколько я помню, вариант `--v` не является классическим.
Впрочем, мой npm версии 2.10.1 его тоже съел.

Comment: я знаю .. но не в этом проблема ..

Answer (score 0):

У меня это решилось запуском терминального приложения из под администратора (машина на Windows 10)